# Get variable number of arguments with PHP SOAP server

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapserver

I am developing a simple PHP SOAP server that receives a request like the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <myFunction>
         <arg1>arg1_value</arg1>
         <arg2>
             <id>3027</id>
             <id>1043</id>
             <id>827</id>
         </arg2>
     </myFunction>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

The first argument (arg1) is mandatory and the second one (arg2) is optional and consists of zero, one or more elements 'id' as shown.

I can access the arg1 value this way:

```
public function myFunction($args){
    $value = $args->arg1;
}
```

What is the best way in PHP to get all the different 'id' arguments within the element arg2?

EDIT:

In my WSDL file I have something like this:

```
    <xsd:element name="myFunction">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="arg1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="arg2" type="tns:multiple_ids" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="multiple_ids">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Is your SOAP server with or without a WSDL?

Comment: Then please add the WSDL and provide some example code related to your question.

Comment: @hakre I've just added a snippet from my wsdl file. Thank you so much